# Prestashop default group auto-update

Tags: sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I come to solicit your help after several days of research.

I have a PrestaShop 1.6.1.4 (multishop). This shop is connected with an ERP for manage orders and customers.

For each customers, we have multi-groups. The default group on my databse is 3 (customers).

My problem : Several times a day, my database auto-update and change my default-group by another value for all customers. On my shop, my customers have to be on "customers" group to use search engine and order... This is a real problem !

Someone can help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: if you own the prestashop install you could activate the general_log in classes/db/MySQL.php file. `mysql_query('SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG_FILE=\'~/www/log1.log\'', $this->link);
        mysql_query('SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG=\'ON\'', $this->link);` in the connect() function.Take care it's very verbose and slow down all yours shops.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! The last update was 2:51 PM. I activated logs, and we'll see after the next update ! I will keep you informed; thanks again :)

Comment: @jacques J'ai vue que tu était FR, j'ai bien ajouté ces lignes, ma base de données c'est remit à jours toutes seules mais aucun fichier log ne s'est créé. As-tu une idée ?

Comment: oui c'est exact FR. may be you need to change the directory ~/www/log1.log. Are you hosted at ovh?

Comment: Yes we are on OVH ! i'll try and keep you informed ! Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @jacques i have this on my MySQL.php :

`public function connect()
    {
     
       [ ... Different IF conditions]
     mysql_query('SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG_FILE=\'www/testSQL.log\'', $this->link); 
     mysql_query('SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG=\'ON\'', $this->link);
        return $this->link;
    }`

Comment: your shop should be in www. Try changing www/testSQL.log to testSQL.log

Comment: my shop is in www folder, i'll try. (As-tu une @mail où je peux te contacter plus facilement ?)

Comment: sorry not much time. After collecting the logs you have a great amount of job to find what's happen with your shop. It's the only way i know to audit a mysql db. Or you can connect an other db with dbPDO driver and others mechanism of audit.

Comment: The log file was not created ....

Answer (score 0):

You should look for some module or custom function, probable related with ERP integration. This should be the cause of group modification. 
Anyway, a complete update of all your customers default group should include 3 keywords you can find in your source code: `update`, `customer` and `id_default_group`. So, if you can find a PHP or MySQL sentence that combine this 3 keywords you will find the problem. But, is this is part of an ERP  integration you should be careful deleting of commenting this code because it can cause a malfunctioning of your integration.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. ERP is installed but we didnt synchronise customers.i checked all my files with Coda and the only occurence is on `Group.php` . I'll check and try to disconnect my ERP. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have webservices activated? Maybe customer update is executed that way.

Comment: How can i check ?

Comment: menu Advanced Parameters -> Webservices ;)

Comment: Webservices are off